# twitter stream api with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am working on real time data visualization project that consumes twitter streaming api
s'.For processing tweets in a server side that is based on rails Framework.

With twitter ruby gem, i can able to fetch the stream tweets

```
topics = ["coffee", "tea"]
client.filter(:track => topics.join(",")) do |tweet|
  puts tweet.text
end
```

With this i need to build a JSON API in Rails.

UPDATE: With JSON API, need to integrate with AngularJS. For building API at real-time, whether i need to store it any database or not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) to build the API, but you can certainly do it in Rails. Simply when a client makes a REST call to the endpoint defined in `routes.rb`, the controller method will itself make a REST call to Twitter and then transform and serialize their result to JSON to return to your client.

Just remember that your clients need to send the CSRF token with their requests to your services for Rails to let them through and maintain session.

In JQuery it might look something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
  }
});
```

As for memory concerns with the volume of data, that depends on how much data you are retrieving, what you are doing with it, the power of your machine, etc. I wouldn't worry if you aren't hitting the Firehose. Let's worry about a memory issue later if it happens. There are always things you can do like caching results, etc. without using a database.